# How to conditionally validate SQL data in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, validation

```
I have this code 
 public static DataSet tipopromocion(string id_edificio,string date_from, string date_to)
    {
        DataSet tipo = new DataSet();

        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring);
        string tipo_promo = "select pr.tipo_promocion from promocion_edificio pe inner join inventario i on i.id_edificio = pe.id_edificio inner join promocion pr on pe.id_promocion=pr.id_promocion where i.id_edificio = '" + id_edificio + "' and i.fecha between '" + date_from + "' and Date_Sub('" + date_to + "',interval 1 Day) and i.fecha between pe.inicio_promo AND pe.fin_promo and date(now()) between pe.inicio_alojamiento and pe.fin_alojamiento AND ( FIND_IN_SET('A',pe.tipo)) group by  pe.id_promocion order by pr.valor_promocion desc";
        MySqlCommand cmd13 = new MySqlCommand(tipo_promo, con);
        MySqlDataAdapter da13 = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd13);
        da13.Fill(tipo);
        return tipo;                               
    }

tipo_promonic
-------------
porcentaje
porcentaje
fixed
discount
porcentaje
discount
discount
fixed
fixed
porcentaje
porcentaje
```

the above result like above table table ok now i am trying to check in     "tipo_promonic" column contains some rows so i am checking if "tipo_promonic" column contains porcentaje,fixed,discount then go to some function else it goto another function ok but in "tipo_promonic" column contains many duplicate values so how to check the condition. please help me out from this problem.

Comment: I really tried to understand you, but I don't. Please clarify and do some proper layouting.

Comment: ok see i have above one column "tipo_promonic" it contains some rows with duplicate values ok. i want to check the "Porcentaje,fixed,discount" rows in that column using conditions and if that checked condition true the it goto diff function so pls help me in that

Comment: you understand my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for a data table. You can make out for `DataAdapter` or `Dataset` according to your need. This is basically a loop which checks each row for a value of a particular column.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows)
{
    if (dr["typo_promonic"].Equals("porcentaje"))
    {
          //your code here.
    }
    else if (dr["tipo_promonic"].Equals("discount"))
    {
          //your code here.
    }
    else
    {
          //your code here.
    }
}
```

You can add more `else...if` as per your options. Whatever you want to do, you can do in those code blocks.

Comment: If this is what OP intended, it doesn't all do what you expect, since the returned value of dr[...] is `object`. Use `string.Equals(..., ...) instead.

Comment: i am getting error "Error 14 'System.Data.DataSet' does not contain a definition for 'Rows' and no extension method 'Rows' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataSet' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\wamp\www\rsrbx\public_html\API_Service\Apartplaya API\Apartplaya API\Apartplaya API\Dal.cs 2439 41 Apartplaya API
"

Comment: You will get. This is how you do for a data table. Try doing it like this. `string qtyInStock = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][index].toString();` and then checking as per the obtained string.

Comment: no still getting error "Cannot convert type 'char' to'System.Data.DataRow' 
"

Comment: Maybe you should assign your DataSet into a DataTable and then loop for all DataRows in that DataTable. And use `dt.Rows[rowindex]["ColumnName"].ToString();` where dt is your DataTable.

Comment: i mean i need to put for loop ?

Comment: Yes. You do have to check for every row, don't you ? You will have to loop for every DataRow and check its value as I mentioned above.And based on that obtained value, put whatever code you want in if...else blocks.

Comment: actually i need to check with two option like percentage and fixed

Comment: Then you should use if...else loop. Check if its percentage, or else fixed. Work around with what I have posted and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 3):

Try Re-framing your SQL query using DISTINCT keyword to avoid Duplicate record

```
string tipo_promo = "select DISTINCT pr.tipo_promocion from promocion_edificio pe inner     ..."
```

Try using DataReader

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring);
string tipo_promo = "select DISTINCT pr.tipo_promocion from promocion_edificio pe inner.."
MySqlCommand cmd13 = new MySqlCommand(tipo_promo, con);
DataReader dr = cmd13.ExecuteReader();
while(dr.Read())
{
  if(dr[0].ToString() == "YourOption")
  {//Do this;}
}
```

Comment: Since when was having duplicates an issue? I didn't read that.

Comment: k but in dr[0].ToString() == "fixed" if next time dr[0] is changed den??

Comment: you can use write column name instead of index like `dr["Column_Name"].ToString`

Comment: i mean like if(dr[column_name]].ToString()=="option"

Comment: can i check multiple options in single if?

Comment: yes you can check. like `if(dr["Column1"].ToString() == "YourOption" && dr["Column2"].ToString() == "YourOption){//your code;}`

Comment: not in different column only single column?

Comment: If there are many condition's use Switch case refer [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx)

Comment: actually i am checking two option or more in single if

Comment: Can you pls elaborate on this